# How to handle empty feature values in Random Forest

Tags: random-forest, feature-selection

I have a question about Random Forest and features. I have put down a table below with an example that should describe the problem I wonder about.

I have 2 Features(SUN and CLOUDS) that are always has a value TRUE/FALSE.

The problem now is that sometimes it can RAIN but I don't want to know if it RAINS or not but IF it RAINS, I want to know about the feature:

**john is here and has an UMBRELLA**

Because the problem is that "john" must in the first place be here in order to know if he has en UMBRELLA or not. So if we put TRUE or FALSE in the empty field it will be wrong because first he has to be here to see if he has an UMBRELLA or not because of the RAIN.

This means that sometimes we will have empty fields for those 2 Features as seen on the first row.

How can we handle this correctly because I need to have values there for the Random Forest to work?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just use a third state instead of true/false for the missing value - why must you use true or false?

Comment: What is hypothes column? And, it seems you have 4 possible data samples overally, and you've crossed out one in the beginning.

Comment: One solution to [tag:missing-data] is [tag:imputation].

Comment: @Pig, the only reason as it is now to use true or false is because I have created a random forest structure that works with true or false. I might perheps see if there is a solution using true or false.

Comment: @ Sycorax says Reinstate Monica, I have a heard about `imputation` but I am not sure if that would work in this scenario? The thing is that in a way there are not any missing values in this case. The empty field under "john is here..." should be blank because he is not here. I should only put TRUE or FALSE there if he actually is here? This is what confuses me how I should think in this case? At the same time the field can't be blank when running the Random Forest algorithm.

Comment: @Gunes, hypothes column is the value to predict for the Random Forest.

Comment: If this is the only reason you force yourself to use true/false - then this is more of an encoding problem. One way to go about this is have an extra feature "john is here ..." is empty or not.

Comment: @Pig, could that really work? If I have an extra feature "john is here..." then `"john is here and has an UMBRELLA"` will still have the empty values or do I miss something?

Comment: I meant you can have a feature "john is here and has an UMBRELLA is empty or not", not just john is here (... because i didn't want to type the whole thing)

Comment: Yes okay, I am not sure still that if I have a feature `"john is here and has an UMBRELLA is empty or not"` I still will have the feature `"john is here and has an UMBRELLA"` which has an empty value and how can those 2 features know of eachother. I am not sure if I miss something, I hope so? :)

Comment: I wonder if this is a valid solution to do. I struggle to understand if this idéa is valid. Let us say that the column `"john is here and has an UMBRELLA"` has a GINI index of `0.45`. Would it be safe to fill in all the empty fields with `TRUE/FALSE` on random so it still has `0.45` in GINI index, which then shouldn't affect the Random Forest algorithm in any way and the prediction should be the same?